# Is there a simpler form of BIP32-like key derivation?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, secp256k1

I've read about [BIP32 key derivation functions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032#Child_key_derivation_.28CKD.29_functions), and also:

> Any Elliptic Curve could work in the BIP32 scheme. The only property
> of a Curve that BIP32 relies on is that a * G + b *G = (a + b mod N) *
> G, which is true for any Elliptic Curve.

(from [Is BIP 32 Technology Cryptographic Curve Agnostic?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/48223/9323).)

Are there simpler forms of weak-child-only key derivations?  (I'm guessing that the HMAC, splitting and concatenation is unneeded for a simpler/weaker scheme.  Such a scheme would just have a large number of weak children and no layers/tree.)

Is a simpler scheme possible?  (I'm asking about cryptography generally, not whether it's a good idea for Bitcoin.)

Comment: `SHA256(entropy | index)`. 1st key = `SHA256(entropy | 0x00000000)`, 2nd key = `SHA256(entropy | 0x00000001)`,...

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast Could you expand that into an answer, please?  I can't understand how these keys relate to the parent keys, as they do not depend on them at all.  In particular I want to derive child public keys from just a parent public key, knowing that the owner of the parent private key can derive the associated child private keys.

Comment: It is a **very very weak** way of deriving child _private_ keys from an initial entropy. If deriving pubkey in a _weak_ way is desired then a similar scheme to BIP-32 for non-hardened children could be used to compute `SHA256(parentPubKey | index)` where child _private_ key is the `parent+child % N`

Comment: Is `parentPrivKey+index % N` the private key for `parentPubKey | index`?  (I cannot see how the unreversable SHA256 can help here at all, but that may well be my lack of knowledge.)